# gap between lines in javascript grid

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop, grid

i made a grid using two javascript for loops,
for some reason i have a fixed gap between the lines in the grid.
i can't understand what couses the gap.

here is what i did.

```
var length = 100;

var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
 text += '<div>';  
    for(var x = 0; x < length; x++){
        text += '<div class="b"></div>';
    }
 text += '</div>';  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/wL3Ljpxo/

I assume the what causes it is that the divs are empty, though they have width and height att...

any help would be great.

TNX

Comment: It’s actually the height of the `br` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the space between the elements and the `<br>` tags get rendered as text, if you set the font size to `0` it will remove the gap while still breaking the line.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/wL3Ljpxo/1/))

```
#demo {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class and apply same height to the outer div.

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   text += '<div class="row">';//  
   for(var x = 0; x < length; x++){
      text += '<div class="b"></div>';
   }
   text += '</div>';
 }
```

CSS

```
.row{
   height: 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/xrcgfm7g/

Please check the fiddle. I have increased the grid size to 5px and removed the background image for clarity.